# how to run automysqlbackup daily

Tags: mysql, backup

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04. I installed:

```
apt-get install automysqlbackup
```

Then I config within `/etc/default/automysqlbackup`, set like this:

```
DBNAMES='TESTDB'
BACKUPDIR="/home/backup"
```

Then when would it run? I wonder.

I based on this [link](http://oloflarsson.se/backups-for-your-linux-server/), When I run command:

```
automysqlbackup
```

I got this error:

```
#Checking for permissions to write to folders:
base folder /var/backup ... does not exist. Exiting.
Note: Supplied more than one argument, ignoring ALL arguments - using     default and global config file only.
Note: /etc/automysqlbackup/automysqlbackup.conf was not found - no global config file.
Error: No basedir found, i.e.
/usr/local/bin/automysqlbackup: line 835: 6: Bad file descriptor
/usr/local/bin/automysqlbackup: line 836: 7: Bad file descriptor
Skipping normal output methods, since the program exited before any log files could be created.
```

But in the link there is no config for it.

Could someone tell me why?

Comment: Well looks like you first issue is the folder `/var/backup` does not exist, have you checked it does?

Comment: But i config `/home/backup`. I checked it many times. And i am sure that i config like that. So that is nonsense for Ubuntu to ask from nowhere. I'm confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick google search revealed, that the script will only look for the basedir (which is hard wired) if the path in BACKUPDIR is not available i.e. does not exist.

Please double check, that

- the folder you entered is valid
- the folder you entered is accessible
- the notation in the config file is valid (quotation marks are required in this one!)

From your description I doubt that you chose the correct path. 
`/home/backup` would let me guess that you try to write to the home folder of a user named "backup". 
Adding folders to the /home directory other than user homes is no good practice. You should always try to avoid this.

Also, from the link you provided, you can read that the script is run as a daily cron, which you can find in /etc/cron.daily

Answer (score 1):

in my case was related with folder permissions, to make it work i either ran command as sudo

`sudo automysqlbackup`

or could change folder's owner

Firs thing is to check the folder's owner, following command will show you who is the owner of the folder

```
ls -al backups
```

probably will be *root*

```
drwxrwx-w-   5 root root  4096 Dec 24 01:47 backups
```

so proceed to change it

`sudo chown your_user /backups`

now it will look like

`drwxrwx-w-   5 your_user root  4096 Dec 24 01:47 backups`

finally run the script

`automysqlbackup`

in this case the dump file gzip file will be placed in

`/backups/daily/your_database_name/`